# Dump data from JSON file to a class variable and access data from outside the class

Tags: python, json, class, class-variables

I'm trying to store some data from a JSON file into a class variable that can be accessed by any other functions outside the class. The data in the JSON file will always be different, so I'm using a thread.

This is an example of my code.

```
class fruitStand(threading.Thread):
    
    fruitAmount = []
    
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    
    def run(self):
        with open("fruitDatafile.json", "r") as fruitDatafile:
                fruitData = json.load(fruitDatafile)
        fruitValue = [
                fruitData["apples"], 
                fruitData["pears"], 
                fruitData["watermelons"], 
                fruitData["lemons"]]
        while True:
            self.fruitAmount.clear()
            for item in fruitValue:
                self.fruitAmount.append(item)
            time.sleep(3100)

fStand = fruitStand()
fStand.start()

print(fStand.fruitAmount)
```

The data seems to be stored correctly into the `fruitAmount` variable, but when I try to access it from outside the class, it shows as if there's nothing in it.

Comment: You are only reading the file once. You probably want to re-read the file at the top of the `while` loop so that you get the current contents each time. (Keep in mind this code has a significant race condition to deal with: the file could be updated *while* you are reading it, not just during the 3100-second sleep period.)

Comment: you want `fruitAmount` to be a list? you won't know which fruit the amount relates to. Also fruitAmount is a class variable and not an instance variable

Answer (score 0):

print(fStand.fruitAmount) is being run before the thread is finished so it is empty. try printing it inside the run method or wait till the thread is complete using
fStand.join() method

Comment: I added fStand.join() but now nothing happens.

Comment: @Uyruaos sorry.  join will wait till the thread is complete. but it will never complete because of the while true loop. so you will either have to put the print statement inside the while loop itself or have it exit at some point from that loop.